# Select statement in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created 2 table with a foreign key of 'skuCode'
My select statment supposed to retrieve data from joint table.
But I am not able to retrieve the data from productDetails table.

Below is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE productItem (
skuCode VARCHAR(8),
productName VARCHAR(32),
productDesc VARCHAR(128),
unitPrice DECIMAL(18,4),
qty INT,
size CHAR(1),
bigImage1 VARCHAR(32),
smallImage2 VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
category VARCHAR(32),
PRIMARY KEY (skuCode)
 ) ENGINE INNODB;

CREATE TABLE productDetails (
detailsId INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
skuCode VARCHAR(8),
status VARCHAR(32),
line1 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
line2 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
line3 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
line4 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
line5 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
line6 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
line7 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
line8 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
line9 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
line10 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (detailsId),
FOREIGN KEY (skuCode) REFERENCES productItem (skuCode)
  ) ENGINE INNODB;
```

Below is my SELECT statement:

```
 $sql = "SELECT productItem.productDesc, productItem.skuCode, productItem.unitPrice, productDetails.line1 FROM productItem, productDetails WHERE productItem.skuCode = productDetails.skuCode ='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["skuCode"])."';";
```

Comment: I hope that you are maintaining some legacy software, and are not using such bad design practices as the ones you illustrate above. Please take a look at PDO and the Normalization rules regarding database design:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   productItem.productDesc, 
   productItem.skuCode, 
   productItem.unitPrice, 
   productDetails.line1 
FROM 
  productItem
INNER JOIN productDetails 
  ON productItem.skuCode = productDetails.skuCode 
WHERE productItem.skuCode ='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["skuCode"])."'
```

Comment: i cant retrieve any data from it

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT productItem.productDesc, productItem.skuCode, productItem.unitPrice, productDetails.line1
FROM productItem INNER JOIN productDetails ON productItem.skuCode = productDetails.skuCode
WHERE productDetails.skuCode = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["skuCode"])."'
```

However, if you prefer joining tables with WHERE:

```
SELECT productItem.productDesc, productItem.skuCode, productItem.unitPrice, productDetails.line1
FROM productItem, productDetails WHERE productItem.skuCode = productDetails.skuCode
AND productDetails.skuCode = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["skuCode"])."'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = "SELECT 
   productItem.productDesc, 
   productItem.skuCode, 
   productItem.unitPrice,
   productDetails.line1 
FROM 
productItem JOIN 
 productDetails ON productItem.skuCode = productDetails.skuCode WHERE productItem.skuCode = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['skuCode'])."'";
```

Try above code this will give the proper result. And also check that what is the value of `$_GET['skuCode']` by echo it. You can use $_REQUEST insteed of $_GET.

Comment: i cant retrieve any data from it

Comment: @benylim have you check what is result of $_GET['skuCode']. I hope this is blank or null.